# Match datetime YYYY-MM-DD object in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas DataFrame` of the form:

```
    id     amount           birth
0   4      78.0      1980-02-02 00:00:00
1   5      24.0      1989-03-03 00:00:00
2   6      49.5      2014-01-01 00:00:00
3   7      34.0      2014-01-01 00:00:00
4   8      49.5      2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

I am interested in only the year, month and day in the `birth` column of the `dataframe`. I tried to leverage on the `Python datetime` from `pandas` but it resulted into an error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1054-02-07 00:00:00
```

The `birth` column is an `object` dtype.

My guess would be that it is an incorrect date. I would **not** like to pass the parameter `errors="coerce"` into the `to_datetime` method, because each item is important and I need just the `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I tried to leverage on the `regex` from `pandas`:

```
df["birth"].str.find("(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})")
```

But this is returning `NANs`. How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: You might need to convert the `df['birth']` into a different datatype before you process it. Can you post the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: `df['Year'] = df['birth'].astype(str).str.extract(r'^(\d{4})', expand=False)` / `df['Month'] = df['birth'].astype(str).str.extract(r'-(\d{1,2})-', expand=False)` / `df['Day'] = df['birth'].astype(str).str.extract(r'^.*-(\d{1,2})', expand=False)`

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) might be your friend

Comment: So do I read correctly when I say you just want a single list returned with all values in `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

Comment: Thats right! Thats what I need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is it possible to have it on one line?

Comment: Try `df[['Year','Month','Day']] = df['birth'].astype(str).str.extract(r'^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2}-(\d{1,2})', expand=False)`

Comment: If you want to identify the offending lines, you could use `df[pd.to_datetime(df.birth, errors='coerce').isna()]`

Comment: I know the offending lines. I want to just pass `YYYY-MM-DD` only

Comment: Or, `df['corrected_birth'] = df['birth'].astype(str).str.replace(r'^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2}-(\d{1,2}).*', r'\1-\2-\3')`, or `df['corrected_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birth'].astype(str).str.replace(r'^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2}-(\d{1,2}).*', r'\1-\2-\3')).dt.date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because not possible convert to datetimes you can use `split` by first whitespace and then select first value:

```
df['birth'] = df['birth'].str.split().str[0]
```

And then if necessary convert to periods.

[Representing out-of-bounds spans](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans).

```
print (df)
   id  amount                birth
0   4    78.0  1980-02-02 00:00:00
1   5    24.0  1989-03-03 00:00:00
2   6    49.5  2014-01-01 00:00:00
3   7    34.0  2014-01-01 00:00:00
4   8    49.5     0-01-01 00:00:00

def to_per(x):
    splitted = x.split('-')
    return pd.Period(year=int(splitted[0]), 
                     month=int(splitted[1]), 
                     day=int(splitted[2]), freq='D')

df['birth'] = df['birth'].str.split().str[0].apply(to_per)

print (df)
   id  amount       birth
0   4    78.0  1980-02-02
1   5    24.0  1989-03-03
2   6    49.5  2014-01-01
3   7    34.0  2014-01-01
4   8    49.5  0000-01-01
```

Comment: I get an error: `DateParseError: year 0 is out of range` and without the period it returns `NANs`

Comment: with `.apply(pd.Period)`

Comment: The birth column is an `object dtype`. But for some reasons I get this error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
` but chaining `astype(str)` gives another error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'`

Comment: @Pythonista - Is possible share column in file? `df['birth'].to_csv('dates.csv', index=False)` ? Because it seems some data related problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214581/discussion-between-pythonista-and-jezrael).